# Need to write a formula in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, formula

I am aiming to calculate stars' radii. The formula requires three variables, of which I will have two, so I should be able to get the third via basic algebra. Here is the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law#Temperature_of_stars):

```
L = 4 π R^2 s T^4
```

Where L is the luminosity in Watts, R is the radius in meters, s is the Stefan-Boltzmann constant (5.67 x 10-8 Wm-2K-4), and T is the star's surface temperature in Kelvin.

I will have the luminosity and temperature, and need to derive the radius. Any help writing a function would be greatly appreciated, as I have no experience with maths in JavaScript.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

Comment: Isn't this just some basic math?

Comment: What do you mean by derivative, do you mean calculating the tangent of the curve since the last point or do you want the partial derivative of R depending of L or T?

Comment: @adminXVII I think OP means "derive" in the sense of calculate, not in the sense of rate of change.

Answer (score 1):

With basic algebra you can deduce that you formula is:
`R=(L/(4*pi*s*T^4))^0.5`

(`x^0.5` is the square root of x)

In js, math functions came from the `Math` package.

To find:

-`^x`, use `Math.pow(base,x);`

-the square root, use `Math.sqrt(base);`

Pi is Math.pi

So basically, your function will look like:

```
var s = ...;
function R(L, T){
  return Math.sqrt((L/(4*Math.pi*s*Math.pow(T,4))));
}
```

---

## DERIVE???

To derive, it's not requiring really much work, only to calculate the difference between two values divided by the time laps.
    var x = 0; // x at last data chunk
    var r = 0; // initial radius

```
function temperature(X, T, L){ // to find the tangent between the last two point, somewhat similar to derivative
  var R = R(L,T);
  var tangent = (R-r)/(X-x);
  r = R;
  x = X;
  return tangent;
}
```

Comment: "need to derive the radius", and with JS.

Comment: @Teemu see my changes

Comment: You still seem to calculate the temperature, OP wants the radius and JavaScript. Where `time` came from?

Comment: @Teemu since a derivative is delta y/delta x, you need a x (or `time` in this case) to compute it. Or maybe the OP wants an partial derivative?

Comment: If I've understood the question correctly, OP wants just to get `R` from `L = 4 π R^2 s T^4`, when they have values for `T`, `s` and `L` already. Your `R` function seems to return it now after you've fixed it, but what is the use for `temperature` function?

Comment: @Teemu if the OP wanted a derivative, `temperature()` provide  function to call to get the tangent to the point where y is R and x is X